# Portable equivalent of OPEN_MAX

Tags: c, linux, posix, bsd

`nftw` wants a parameter for number of file handles to use, and doesn't seem to have a way to say 'as many as possible'. Specifying 255 seems to work on Linux, but fails on BSD. Apparently OPEN_MAX is the recommended solution on BSD, but I can't use this as it doesn't work on Linux.

Is there a portable equivalent of OPEN_MAX that will work on both Linux and BSD?

Alternatively, is there a portable number, some number large enough to not slow things down, that is portable for practical purposes (ideally specified in POSIX, or at least that will work on every Unix-like system with significant market share)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd Ed](http://www.apuebook.com/) gives us the following code which should work everywhere; though it is pretty clever, I think it is a little unfortunate it doesn't *also* check the rlimits of the process, since the rlimits can further constrain how many open files a process may use. That aside, here's the code from [The Master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Richard_Stevens):

```
#ifdef  OPEN_MAX
static long openmax = OPEN_MAX;
#else
static long openmax = 0;
#endif

/*
 * If OPEN_MAX is indeterminate, we're not
 * guaranteed that this is adequate.
 */
#define OPEN_MAX_GUESS  256

long
open_max(void)
{
    if (openmax == 0) {     /* first time through */
        errno = 0;
        if ((openmax = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)) < 0) {
            if (errno == 0)
                openmax = OPEN_MAX_GUESS;   /* it's indeterminate */
            else
                err_sys("sysconf error for _SC_OPEN_MAX");
        }
    }

    return(openmax);
}
```

(`err_sys()` is provided in the `apue.h` header with the sources -- should be easy to code a replacement for your routine.)

Answer (score 2):

See [`getdtablesize`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getdtablesize). It has a conformance note:

> SVr4, 4.4BSD (the getdtablesize() function first appeared in 4.2BSD). It is not specified in POSIX.1-2001; portable applications should employ sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) instead of this call.

Comment: It even checks the rlimits. Nice. :)

Comment: IMHO getrlimit() is the POSIX equivalent of getdtablesize