# _iob declaration in stdio header

Tags: c, linux, unix

From stdio.h header there is a declaration that I cant understand the purpose of it, OPEN_MAX is defined as 20

```
extern FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX];
```

**what  is this _iob array and what is the purpose of it?** It seems to be important because stdin,stdout and stderr is defined as (&_iob[0]),(&_iob[1]), and (&_iob[2]);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is OPEN\_MAX defined for Linux systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042824/where-is-open-max-defined-for-linux-systems)

Comment: it doesnt mention _iob at all

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798083.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It is the table of open files of a process. In UNIXes, this table is not so visible, but under Windows that table is accessible.

I can remember that `iob` stands for Input/Output Blocks.